# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1) Error in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I know this error has something to do with memory management but i must admit i'm stumped! Been programming in objective c for about 3 weeks and all this managing memory stuff is confusing!
What is basically happening is that i have this mapview in a tableview. When clicking the back button to leave the mapview and return to the main menu i get the error above.
Here is the code from the Header file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {

    IBOutlet MKMapView* mapView;
    BOOL locate;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView* mapView;

@end
```

and the Implementation file

```
#import "MapViewController.h"

@implementation MapViewController

@synthesize mapView;

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    mapView.delegate=self;
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:mapView];

    [self.mapView.userLocation addObserver:self
                                forKeyPath:@"location"
                                   options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
                                   context:nil];
    locate = YES;

}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{

    if (locate == YES) {
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;

    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta  = 0.1; 
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.1;
    region.span = span;

    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
        locate = NO;
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [mapView release];
    [self.mapView.userLocation removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"location"];
    [self.mapView removeFromSuperview];
    self.mapView = nil;
}

@end
```

Can anybody shed some light for me? :)

Comment: I've tried commenting out various lines of code to see if i could work it out but it's the same thing every time, as i said i'm quite new to this so any help, even with debugging, would be appreciated :) (Sorry to be a clueless pain in the backside lol)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`[super dealloc];` must be the last call in `dealloc`

also after `[mapView release];` mapView might be gone already.

try

```
- (void)dealloc {

    [self.mapView.userLocation removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"location"];
    [self.mapView removeFromSuperview];
    [mapView release];
    self.mapView = nil; 
    [super dealloc];  // at this point self — that is the same object as super — is not existent anymore
}
```

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xa0e69c14) but the memory address changes each time. Just edited to add some clarity as i forgot to mention when the app is crashing >.<

Comment: GOT IT! You were right, i commented out mapView release and it is no longer crashing. So it was obviously releasing it then trying to release again. Thanks :) (Says i cant accept this answer for 5 minutes, so bare with me for ya rep mate)

Answer (score 0):

This error can be also caused by incompatible API (eg. you build for iOS 6.0, but use a method introduced only in iOS >= 8.2)

Comment: This is not an answer, more like a comment.

Comment: I have not enough reputation to post comments, let it be )